# catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start

Tags: jsp, tomcat, lifecycleexception

I'm trying to make my Tomcat runs but I keep getting error message `Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.`

I've tried to add `commons-logging-1.2.jar` to fix the problem, but it's still not working. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Below is the error log (UPDATED). It does indicate the servlet mapping error with my countycreate jsp file.

```
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
Jul 11, 2020 2:13:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial-servlet]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial-servlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [countycreate] in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3176)
    at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1603)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more

Jul 11, 2020 2:13:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial-servlet]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial-servlet]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [countycreate] in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3176)
    at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1603)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>County</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>CountyCreate.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <!--
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CountyCreate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.CountyCreate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CountyCreate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/countycreate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  -->
</web-app>
```

And this is one of my servlet file.. This file locates in the src > servlet folder in my directory:

```
    package whetherweather.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import whetherweather.dal.DemographicDao;
import whetherweather.dal.CountyDao;
import whetherweather.model.County;


@WebServlet("/usercreate")
public class CountyCreate extends HttpServlet {
    
    protected CountyDao countyDao;
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        countyDao = CountyDao.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Map for storing messages.
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
        req.setAttribute("messages", messages);
        //Just render the JSP.   
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/CountyCreate.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Map for storing messages.
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
        req.setAttribute("messages", messages);

        // Retrieve and validate county id.
        Integer countyId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("idCounty"));
        if (countyId == null) {
            messages.put("success", "Invalid idCounty");
        } else {
            // Create county.
            Integer getcountyId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("idCounty"));
            String getCountyName = req.getParameter("CountyName");
            Integer getDemoId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Demographics_idDemographics"));
            String getState = req.getParameter("State");
 
       
            try {
                // Exercise: parse the input for StatusLevel.
                County county = new County(getcountyId, getCountyName, getDemoId, getState);
                county = countyDao.create(county);
                messages.put("success", "Successfully created " + countyId);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
        
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/CountyCreate.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: more of logs? are you running any other server?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the problem is because of the wrong mapping (e.g. in `web.xml` or within the annotation). Post the content of your `web.xml`.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated my error logs and xml file.

Comment: @TranPham - Do you have any mapping like `/Trial-servlet` in any of your servlets?

Comment: No I don't. I just update one of my servlet file in the question

Comment: @TranPham - Unfortunately, it looks like there exists a mapping, `Trial-servlet` because the error message is  `Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial-servlet]]`. Probably, you might have deployed some other application which has this mapping. If you are not able to clean it up, I suggest you try with a new Tomcat instance. I do not see any problem with your code/config.